# Can't get dataTable to populate with Codeigniter and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

I have gone through several answers on SO as well as a few tutorials and the documentation on ajax/dataTables. My dataTable will still not populate with JSON data.

HTML:

```
<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Exam Name</th>
                <th>School</th>
                <th colspan="2">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Student Name</th>
            <th>Exam Name</th>
            <th>School</th>
            <th colspan="2">Action</th>
        </tfoot>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Datatables
        $('#table').DataTable({
            "url": "<?php echo site_url('exams/ajax_list'); ?>",
        });

    });

</script>
```

ajax_list PHP function in Exams controller:

```
public function ajax_list() {
    $list = $this->exam_model->get_datatables();
    $data = array();
    foreach ($list as $exam) {
        $row = array();
        $row[] = $exam->exam_status;
        $row[] = $exam->first_name . " " . $exam->last_name;
        $row[] = $exam->exam_name;
        $row[] = $exam->exam_school;

        $data[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

From what I can see when navigating to the method, the json_encode outputs correctly, but the dataTable is still empty.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: have you double checked the path of ajax_list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally got it to work... Thanks for giving me the chance to play with this as its all brand new to me. It was a bit of a bugga, but like everything else it turns out to be simple.

I didn't set this up in CI but that wont matter...

After drudging through the documentation I came up with this...

**1.Change your "url" to "ajax".**
I'll assume your path you use is correct. Alter what I have to yours.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Datatables
        $('#table').DataTable({
            "ajax":  "./ajax_list.php" // change this to suit.

        });
    });
</script>
```

**2. Remove the colspan="2" in your th tags.**
It don't like it unless you use some other option I didn't look into...

**3. And finally change your json_encode to...**

```
echo json_encode(['data'=>$data]);
```

And hopefully that gets you up and running... The documentation is pretty good so I suggest giving that a good going over.

Comment: I love you @TimBrownLaw. Doing all 3 of these things worked. I think I was just not reading the documentation thoroughly enough. Table is now populated!!!

Comment: @TimothyFisher Well a thank you would have sufficed but I am glad it's all happening for you now. Cheers!

Comment: Lose the colspan="2" in your th tags: Can You Please Elaborate it more. @TimBrownlaw

Comment: @ankit - translated... it means to remove the colspan="2".